# Disabling boxy appearance of info bar

Tags: fonts

I've disabled my mode-line's boxy appearance with

```
    (set-face-attribute 'mode-line nil :box nil)
    (set-face-attribute 'mode-line-inactive nil :box nil))
```

Is it possible to do the same for the top bar that appears after `M-x info`?

Comment: Do you see a boxy header line in Info if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not, then something in your init file is producing that appearance: bisect your init file to find the culprit. (You can also remove the header line altogether by setting option `Info-use-header-line` to `nil`.)

Comment: @Drew, you're right, I should have checked that.  I suspect the Zenburn theme is what causes it.

Comment: In that case, you might want to delete your question.

Comment: @Drew, why? it's still answerable by anyone with a similar theme/init.

Comment: Then edit your question to make it specifically about use of that theme. Isolate the cause of the problem in your init file, and pose a specific question about that problem. Comments can be deleted at any time, and there is nothing in your question that speaks to the real problem. IOW, move anything relevant to the question itself.